# Changes not recompiled on Pages in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2005

My page "abc.aspx.cs" contains "WebMethods" to enable ajax calling from client.
If any changes in WebMethod are made then in order to see those changes I have first stop visual studio, then stop visual studio inbuilt application server and then restart the application again.

Since its a large project and need login, it takes too much time to follow this procedure.

So kindly let me know whether this behaviour is configurable or there are no option.

In "abc.aspx.cs" page

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MethodName(string data)
{
    //Stuff to do
    //changes done here
}
```

Restart the project to see changes.

Comment: You have to do like this way only.

Comment: Please explain a little bit...